# Find Documents with mongo-driver/mongo Using Expression for Value in Key/Value Pairs

Tags: mongodb, go, find, key-value

I am using https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo and can't seem to figure out how to insert an expression for the "value" of one of the key/value pairs when finding documents. My code is as follows:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{{"date", "$gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (1000*60*60*24*100)))"}, {"enabled", true}})
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve documents that are only a certain number of days old with respect to the current date. The query doesn't fail but returns 0 documents. The value for date is an expression but if I don't surround it with double quotes, Go doesn't treat it as a key/value pair.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need another layer of nesting (eg another bson.D). What you want is for your "value" here itself to be its own key/value pair where $gte is the key and the calculated date is the value. Right now you're concatenating the two into a single string value (which matches no documents)

Comment: Thanks, your approach worked as I noted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a string value to the `date` field in the filter. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/query-document/#specify-a-query), the syntax is:

```
filter := bson.D{{"<field>", bson.D{{"<operator>", "<value>"}}}}
```

Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import (
    "context" 
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson" 
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options" 
    "time"
)


cursor, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.D{
    {"date", bson.D{
        {"$gte", time.Now().AddDate(0, 0, -100)},
    }},
    { "enabled", true },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Your solution worked!